# Firebase cloud functions - automatic authentication setup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

is it possible to create some kind of automatic preset thingy, where every cloud function that has an http trigger has authentication set to "Allow unauthenticated" ? I want to do it without having to manually set it via the gcloud console/listing out all the functions via gcloud cli. Thx

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to choose this setting for every function you create.  You could make it easier for yourself by writing a shell script that sets this access when you want to create or deploy the function.